# The correct way to approach polymorphism in this case (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have been given a task that can be simplified to this scenario:

Customers need to order boxes and these boxes can come in different sizes, the different sizes can be ordered in certain colours (but not all colours) and have different qualities (but not all qualities).

Now I believe the best way to approach this would be to make the box class the abstract class and have the different boxes extend the box class to prevent repetitive code, but then the issue comes in, how do I check an order a client puts in is valid without storing static variables in the class (this class cannot have this colour etc.)?

My solution is to simply put static variables in each extension of the class and then check each class without initialising a new object but it means having repeating variable declarations in each class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Colour" and "quality" sound like properties (i.e. member variables) of a box, not subtypes of a box.  Therefore, you probably don't want polymorphism for this.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to hard code decisions into the order process, if I extend them out I can just look through the new classes to see if the order fits any of the box requirements or am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: You have been given a task? Or you have been given homework?

Comment: @JamieB: I don't fully understand your scenario.  But I don't think you want `BigRedBox`, `BigGreenBox`, `SmallRedBox`, `SmallGreenBox`, etc. each as a different subclass.

Comment: Homework makes it sound simple :)

Comment: That's where I am at, at the moment Oli but I am trying to get around the problem of having each subclass holding static information about what they can do, the task also wants the class to then be initialised and a method to be executed in the class to calculate the cost which is fine, that is inherited from the box class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you you're willing to have a really complicated class hierarchy, you might want to consider using a look-up table instead of inheritance/polymorphism. It will definitely be easier to follow and maintain.

The accessors to your look-up table might be something like

```
Colors getColors(Size);
Colors getColors(Quality);
Qualities getQualities(Size);
Qualities getQualities(Color);
```

etc.

---

**Update**

The only sane way you can use OOP principles here is if you have enough information about the relationships to define a hierarchy.

For instance:

```
public abstract Shape {
  Color color;
  public setColor(Color c) { this.color = c}
  public abstract draw();
  ...
}
public Ellipse extends Shape ...
public Circle extends Ellipse ... /* this might be a stretch for mathemeticians */
```

If you've got more info about the assignemnt, post it.

Comment: Yep, there can still be subclasses of "Box" for various types of boxes (not color, and probably not size, but shoe boxes vs cigar boxes etc), but put the attributes into a table.  Don't overcomplicate.

Comment: The task revolves around the whole polymorphism thing so I need to do it this way, I am just looking for the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, I don't think it's a very good one. It's representative of the real world, but it's not a good polymorphism exercise.

Comment: Ok basically each box grade (we have to eventually figure out what grade box it is) first of all has a minimum and maximum thickness (1-5), next up there are only certain colours each grade can be, then there are other qualities that some grades have like lamination and strengthening which will decide what grade it is in based on the data that is entered. We are given the low mark method which is the method I am trying to avoid "Having an ultimate if statement that chooses 'if thickness > 0 and colour is red it must be grade 1'".

Answer (score 1):

I would use a series of `enums` and an abstract Box class:

```
public static enum Color {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN, ETC
}

public static enum Quality {
    POOR, AVERAGE, GOOD, EXCELLENT
}

public static abstract class Box {
    private final EnumSet<Color> colors;
    private final EnumSet<Quality> qualities;
    private final String name;

    protected Box(String name, EnumSet<Color> colors, EnumSet<Quality> qualities) {
        this.name = name;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.qualities = qualities;
    }

    // getters/setters and methods for dealing with validating colors and qualities
}

public static class BoxType1 extends Box {
    public MyBox() {
        super("Type 1", EnumSet.of(Color.RED, Color.BLUE),
              EnumSet.of(Quality.AVERAGE, Quality.GOOD, Quality.EXCELLENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am aware of enums etc, I am more familiar with C#. This isn't the level that the class is at yet so I wouldn't be able to do this, I lost marks for handing in something that used try/catch in the second week because I was using things we hadn't covered :)

Comment: I don't think I agree with this. You have to add more Enums for each new attribute, and a new extension of Box for each BoxType.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need static variables as you do not need information common to all objects. Do you?
Your abstract class can have abstract method validate() and your derived class knows which is validate box and can have an implementation within it. I hope it makes sense, let me know if something else you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is, to use the abstract method you have to instantiate the class.  You'd like to know what's "legal" before you instantiate the class.

Comment: Not sure we are on the same page, I need a check to be done once the order form is submitted and the applet should be able to quickly figure out first of all if the order fits any of the boxes and then of course pick it, initialise an object of that box and run a method from that object.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your task's scenario, it's pretty hard to suggest something. You should provide more info about the kind of interactions happening between clients and orders and boxes...

Comment: It isn't that complicated, there are no clients, there are no orders basically all that has to happen with the app is it needs to show polymorphism, it says here "Show use of abstract class". All the applet has to do is validate the input isn't incorrect (letters instead of numbers) then figure out which box the data matches and execute a method inside that box object that calculates the cost. I just want to get the most efficient way to store what each box can and can't have without repeating code.

Comment: Well in that case, and if you can't use enums, I wouldn't look further than your initial idea...

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure if you sould solve this by subclassing ...

despite that, you can use the factory pattern for this

you can create a factory for boxes that can also give statements about what boxes are legal constructions, or even give you a list of legal boxes to choose from ...