# Polymorphism and boxes

Tags: java

I am trying to get round a rather annoying issue in my homework.

Basically the task is to create a fake ordering UI where the user puts in some variables about the type of box they need to order and then presses a button. Behind the scenes the app should be validating which pipe fits the users needs and then instantiate a new box object and execute the methods inside the new object.

I am basically struggling to find a way that isn't stupid which allows for the UI to validate a choice before creating a new object, a method is given to us to begin with and is referred to a 'brute force method' which has a massive if statement inside the button click which does the checking there, now I am 100% sure there is an easier way to do it although the only thing I can come up with is holding constants or statics in a class and checking each class before creating one.

Scenario:
The idea is that each box the company sells has certain features (thickness, laminated, colour and other things) while others boxes don't, I need to be able to figure out when the order button is clicked what box the order fits once I know the box type that the order fits I should create a new object of that box and run the cost() method, if it doesn't fit any box the company sells then I should prompt the user. The program must use abstraction.

The class isn't at a high level at the moment so I can't use enums and lookup tables which is causing me problems.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There is no reason for code, I am asking for methods (not code) on how this could be done.

Comment: Tokenizer is too high level for the teaching class that I am in.

Comment: Too high level, this class is in the first year we have only been taught basic data fields and private/public/static variables. I understand the methods people are suggesting (I work in C#) but I am struggling to find a way to implement this at the level the class is at.

Comment: Cosine similarity can be implemented easily, it's just a basic math and it wouldn't require any "high level" Java code. "Some code , please?" still stands.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251195/the-correct-way-to-approach-polymorphism-in-this-case-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like they just want you to show several classes (one for each type of box) which all inherit or implement a common interface with methods like 'getWidth', 'getHeight' etc. You can then write a simple loop to iterate over a collection of box type instances, evaluating their suitability before returning the list of compatible box types.

Comment: Yes but how would I do this without instantiating the box before hand?

Comment: You do instantiate! Unless you want to use reflection or something like that. Bit overkill though given the level of the assignment.